# Is [talmud-bavli] useful?

Tags: discussion, specific-tag

Is there anything about [talmud-bavli](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/talmud-bavli) that cannot be covered by [talmud-gemara](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/talmud-gemara) and/or the pertinent masechet tags?

There are under 60 questions, many of which are already tagged under other Gemara tags.

Note: I'm not asking about [talmud-yerushalmi](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/talmud-yerushalmi), as it is a different format than the Bavli, and as such can have different types of questions.

Comment: What if your question is about Bavli specifically and not Yerushalmi?

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/22491/what-is-the-source-for-a-womans-voice-as-ervah/28865#comment70487_28865

Comment: possibly parallel http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/438/759

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rethinking this now... both are actually appropriate tags. [talmud-bavli](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/talmud-bavli) and [talmud-yerushalmi](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/talmud-yerushalmi) refer to two separate works, and can be tagged as such.

There are actually several questions for which [talmud-gemara](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/talmud-gemara) is wholly appropriate, for example (to list a few):

- [High School Math in the Talmud](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/22870/high-school-math-in-the-talmud)
- [What does "the Talmud" mean in the Talmud?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/4886/what-does-the-talmud-mean-in-the-talmud)
- [Insults in the gemarah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/14868/insults-in-the-gemarah)

The only thing now is to clean up the tag a bit and remove questions that only apply to a certain part of the talmud.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps the one to get rid of is [talmud-gemara](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/talmud-gemara). Questions that address Talmud generally mostly actually address Bavli generally. Any questions that address both Bavli and Yerushalmi can tag them both, which makes sense, as they're two distinct bodies of work.

Comment: With a [tag:gemara] synonym pointing to Bavli (as that's the way to bet)?  Do we have questions in [tag:talmud-gemara] that are about the talmud(s) generally -- rules of derivation, history, etc?  (I haven't reviewed the ~60 questions on the tag.)

Comment: @MonicaCellio s/~60/239 (plus 19 deleted)/

Comment: @MonicaCellio Perhaps http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/40517/5151 and http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/37828/5151 just to name a couple.

Comment: @msh210 oops, you're right -- I picked up the number from the question but that's another tag.

Comment: @Scimonster also http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/10873/472, which I think is "of a type", not a unique case, but I haven't gone looking further.  (I just happen to remember this one. :-) )

Comment: @Scimonster 40517 I *suspect* was intended by its asker to be about the _Bavli_ only; 37828 is not about Talmud at all, and should be tagged only [tag:amoroim] and [tag:tannaim]; and 10873 is not about Talmud specifically (e.g. it's about _Sifre_ also) and shouldn't be so tagged. Just my opinions.

Comment: @msh210 40517 seemed to be referring to both to me. 37828 sounds like you're right. While 10873 might also refer to Sifre, it does ask about Talmud.

Comment: Since I've never studied Yerushalmi (except, IIRC, for a short digression there in daf yomi), when I ask a question about the talmud I have *no idea* if it applies to both.  I suspect I'm not the only one.  So "just tag both" probably won't produce consistent results.